# Column/Cell Versioning in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am testing out Cassandra and trying to figure out cell versioning. I am storing financial instrument price ticks - with a twist - the message stream I am reading is delta-based. Meaning I will get a message for some key (lets say Stock Symbol and Date). The first message of the day has a message time, all tags (let's say they are bid price, ask price, and many other pieces of information). Throughout the day, I receive messages that have JUST the tags/fields that have changed and a message time. So maybe the next message will be Stock Symbol, Date, message time and ask price, then another message for that key with other tags changed. None of the values that have not changed are ever repeated on later messages. It would not be acceptable to store the first message and then additional rows for just the tags that have changed. That would force the client to have to fully reassemble state at any given point in time.

Users have the need to see that full state of that key at some point in time, or the last N ticks (full state of all tags), or all of the ticks in some time frame. Here's an example of what the messaging would look like:

*Message key is StockSymbol and Date (meaning every message that has the same StockSymbol and Date is an update to the tick. Let’s say it’s price)

4 Messages Received:

StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.00, BidPrice =1.05, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=1

StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.05, BidPrice =1.10, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=2

StockSymbol = 1, BidPrice =1.15, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=3

StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.10, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=4

So there are 4 messages with the same key. I would want the db to look like this (note that fields that didn’t change are present on the inserts:

Row 1: StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.00, BidPrice =1.05, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=1

Row 2: StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.05, BidPrice =1.10, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=2

Row 3: StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.05, BidPrice =1.15, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=3

Row 4: StockSymbol = 1, AskPrice= 1.10, BidPrice =1.15, Date=2016-08-15, MessageTime=4

...or have a way to just add a new version to the columns that have changed, in a single row. Kind of like what HBase does.

There are billions of these messages per day. Not all on one key, so there will not be billions of versions of any column. Maybe a few thousand.

I am digging into a bunch of modeling options, but I thought it was a good idea to post to the community as well.

I hope that makes sense...

Thank you.

Comment: And thus far the only real way I have come up with is to read N messages in a batch, select out existing rows by key, update/overlay the changed value(s) and re-insert in batch, thus creating a copy. The newest copy would have a flag LATEST = 'Y' (possibly)

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to create a new table that matches this schema:

```
StockSymbol  PartitionKey,
Date  PartitionKey,
Type   ClusteringKey,
Value
```

The TYPE field's value will be "BidPrice", or "AskPrice" based on your sample data.

The VALUE field's values will be the value for the BidPrice (1.05) or AskPrice (1.00).

This allows for one value to be stored for each STOCKSYMBOL, for each DATE, and for each TYPE.  You will be able to query by the SYMBOL and DATE to receive a single partition with all of the TYPEs of data.

The thing is you will have to insert the data by TYPE (one call for each type).  Any time data is inserted it will overwrite the previous VALUE for that STOCKSYMBOL, DATE, and TYPE.  This will ensure it is always the most up to date information.

Comment: Thanks gsteiner. The problem with that is that I need "all" versions, meaning, what was the full state of bid and ask between these 2 times, or at some exact time in the past? Also, I gave a simple example for brevity. There will actually be 100s of columns. They all come populated on the first message of the day for that key, then throughout the day, as values for a particular field change, a new message is issued with just that change on it (say 1 or 2 fields, but could be more). Any retrieval of that data should show the full state at that point in time of all of the tags. Yep, messy.